# how to extract the specific word from a string?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a file with multiple lines and want to extract the first three words of every line.

```
str = []

str = [
Feb 17 07:10:07 afg-prod-web2 journal: afg-prod-web2 statistics: 192.168.28.12 - 200 - "{\x0A    \x22identifier\x22: {\x0A        \x22company_code\x22: \x22TSC\x22,\x0A        \x22product_type\x22: \x22airtime-ctg\x22,\x0A        \x22host_type\x22: \x22android\x22\x0A    },\x0A    \x22id\x22: {\x0A        \x22type\x22: \x22guest\x22,\x0A        \x22group\x22: \x22guest\x22,\x0A        \x22uuid\x22: \x22fd2dfcdc-ade2-11e6-8404-0242ac110003\x22,\x0A        \x22device_id\x22: \x222f504f5ed3c64934\x22\x0A    },\x0A    \x22stats\x22: [\x0A        {\x0A            \x22timestamp\x22: \x222017-02-16T23:29:57+0000\x22,\x0A            \x22software_id\x22: \x22A-ACTG\x22,\x0A            \x22action_id\x22: \x22open_app\x22,\x0A            \x22values\x22: {\x0A                \x22device_id\x22: \x222f504f5ed3c64934\x22,\x0A                \x22language\x22: \x22en\x22\x0A            }\x0A        }\x0A    ]\x0A}"

Feb 17 07:10:07 afg-prod-web2 journal: afg-prod-web2 statistics: 192.168.28.12 - 200 - "{\x0A    \x22identifier\x22: {\x0A        \x22company_code\x22: \x22TSC\x22,\x0A        \x22product_type\x22: \x22airtime-ctg\x22,\x0A        \x22host_type\x22: \x22android\x22\x0A    },\x0A    \x22id\x22: {\x0A        \x22type\x22: \x22guest\x22,\x0A        \x22group\x22: \x22guest\x22,\x0A        \x22uuid\x22: \x22fd2dfcdc-ade2-11e6-8404-0242ac110003\x22,\x0A        \x22device_id\x22: \x222f504f5ed3c64934\x22\x0A    },\x0A    \x22stats\x22: [\x0A        {\x0A            \x22timestamp\x22: \x222017-02-16T23:29:57+0000\x22,\x0A            \x22software_id\x22: \x22A-ACTG\x22,\x0A            \x22action_id\x22: \x22open_app\x22,\x0A            \x22values\x22: {\x0A                \x22device_id\x22: \x222f504f5ed3c64934\x22,\x0A                \x22language\x22: \x22en\x22\x0A            }\x0A        }\x0A    ]\x0A}"

Feb 17 07:10:07 afg-prod-web2 journal: afg-prod-web2 statistics: 192.168.28.12 - 200 - "{\x0A    \x22identifier\x22: {\x0A        \x22company_code\x22: \x22TSC\x22,\x0A        \x22product_type\x22: \x22airtime-ctg\x22,\x0A        \x22host_type\x22: \x22android\x22\x0A    },\x0A    \x22id\x22: {\x0A        \x22type\x22: \x22guest\x22,\x0A        \x22group\x22: \x22guest\x22,\x0A        \x22uuid\x22: \x22fd2dfcdc-ade2-11e6-8404-0242ac110003\x22,\x0A        \x22device_id\x22: \x222f504f5ed3c64934\x22\x0A    },\x0A    \x22stats\x22: [\x0A        {\x0A            \x22timestamp\x22: \x222017-02-16T23:29:57+0000\x22,\x0A            \x22software_id\x22: \x22A-ACTG\x22,\x0A            \x22action_id\x22: \x22open_app\x22,\x0A            \x22values\x22: {\x0A                \x22device_id\x22: \x222f504f5ed3c64934\x22,\x0A                \x22language\x22: \x22en\x22\x0A            }\x0A        }\x0A    ]\x0A}"

Feb 17 07:10:07 afg-prod-web1 journal: afg-prod-web1 statistics: 192.168.28.12 - 200 - "{\x0A    \x22identifier\x22: {\x0A        \x22company_code\x22: \x22TSC\x22,\x0A        \x22product_type\x22: \x22airtime-ctg\x22,\x0A        \x22host_type\x22: \x22android\x22\x0A    },\x0A    \x22id\x22: {\x0A        \x22type\x22: \x22guest\x22,\x0A        \x22group\x22: \x22guest\x22,\x0A        \x22uuid\x22: \x22fd2dfcdc-ade2-11e6-8404-0242ac110003\x22,\x0A        \x22device_id\x22: \x222f504f5ed3c64934\x22\x0A    },\x0A    \x22stats\x22: [\x0A        {\x0A            \x22timestamp\x22: \x222017-02-16T23:29:57+0000\x22,\x0A            \x22software_id\x22: \x22A-ACTG\x22,\x0A            \x22action_id\x22: \x22open_app\x22,\x0A            \x22values\x22: {\x0A                \x22device_id\x22: \x222f504f5ed3c64934\x22,\x0A                \x22language\x22: \x22en\x22\x0A            }\x0A        }\x0A    ]\x0A}"]
```

I want to extract the `date` ie.  `Feb 17 07:10:07` from every line and put that in an array.

I tried applying a for loop but it gives error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code I tried :

```
for i in splitdata:
            abc  = splitdata[logcount]
            aa = abc.split()
            if(aa[0] == "Feb"):
                aaa = "".join([aa[0],' ',aa[1],' ',aa[2]])
                logtime.append(aaa)
                logcount += 2   
            else:
                pass
        print logtime
```

Comment: Could you mention wat is splitdata & logcount values also?

Comment: splitdata is the str that i had mentioned and logcount is the count for the next line ie to get the next date

Comment: I think the error is because you have blank lines in between and in that case "aa" will not have any data.

Comment: In the file there is no blank line in between

Comment: Am I correct list items should be separated by comma? Comma is absent between items in the list. Moreover, logcount = 0 when the loop starts? If logcount value is other than 0, then index is out of range as there is only one element in list str.

Comment: yes it is seperated by comma this i had put just for the sake of reading clearly and the logcount is 0 when loop starts

Comment: Why logcount += 2 ??? Instead of logcount, you can use i and no need to increment. If you want to use logcount, then it should be logcount += 1 When you add more than one, index will be out of range as it jumps two @ a step

Answer (score 0):

if your log is being saved in a file called log.log you can get dates by doing something like this:

```
with open('log.log') as f: 
    log_time = []
    for line in f:
        log_time.append(line[:15])
print(log_time)
```

Comment: Did you consider what happens if the line is empty? I think it will generate the same error `IndexError: list index out of range` which is op trying to solve.

Comment: `In the file there is no blank line in between` check comment by @Tintin on his Question

Comment: Then, why do you think `IndexError ` is getting raised?

Answer (score 0):

You just check the len(splitted string) to avoid such error. There is lot of scope in improving your code.

- Use method that can be reused
- check the len of list before accessing by index
- You dont need to have brackets for if condition in python
- Use list comprehension in a smart way
- Code you have used to join list shows you need to learn a lot in python. Best of luck!

```py
In [1]: sample_text = """Feb 17 07:10:07 afg-prod-web2 journal: afg-prod-web2 statistics: 192.168.28.12 - 200 - "{\x0A
   ...:  \x22identifier\x22: {\x0A        \x22company_code\x22: \x22TSC\x22,\x0A        \x22product_type\x22: \x22airtime
   ...: -ctg\x22,\x0A        \x22host_type\x22: \x22android\x22\x0A    },\x0A    \x22id\x22: {\x0A        \x22type\x22: \
   ...: x22guest\x22,\x0A        \x22group\x22: \x22guest\x22,\x0A        \x22uuid\x22: \x22fd2dfcdc-ade2-11e6-8404-0242a
   ...: c110003\x22,\x0A        \x22device_id\x22: \x222f504f5ed3c64934\x22\x0A    },\x0A    \x22stats\x22: [\x0A
   ...: {\x0A            \x22timestamp\x22: \x222017-02-16T23:29:57+0000\x22,\x0A            \x22software_id\x22: \x22A-A
   ...: CTG\x22,\x0A            \x22action_id\x22: \x22open_app\x22,\x0A            \x22values\x22: {\x0A
   ...: \x22device_id\x22: \x222f504f5ed3c64934\x22,\x0A                \x22language\x22: \x22en\x22\x0A            }\x0A
   ...:         }\x0A    ]\x0A}"""

In [2]: def get_time_from_log(log_text):
   ...:     log_text_split = log_text.split(" ")
   ...:     if len(log_text_split) < 3:
   ...:         pass
   ...:     elif log_text_split[0] == "Feb":
   ...:         return " ".join(log_text_split[0:3])
   ...:

In [3]: get_time_from_log(sample_text)
Out[3]: 'Feb 17 07:10:07'
```